# What does "LMA" stand for?

Tags: canonical

After recent issues with an Ubuntu VM I looked into support options where Canonical states:

> Security and support for open source database, LMA, server and cloud-native apps

I usually know my IT abbreviations pretty well, but what does *LMA* stand for?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LMA Services means Logging, Monitoring and Aggregation services and currently includes: Nagios, Prometheus, Alertmanager,  Grafana, Graylog and Elasticsearch.

Source: https://ubuntu.com/legal/ubuntu-advantage-service-description

Comment: I accepted this as the answer, since the link is more current.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe we'll let you decide.  This link states that it is Logging, Monitoring and Alerting.

https://assets.ubuntu.com/v1/6063f97a-UbuntuAdvantage-datasheet_July-2019.pdf

Comment: Don't you love it, when marketing departments can't decide what their fancy new acronyms actually stand for? Oh, Canonical....

Comment: @OttoEisen So true.  Or when marketing thinks it means one thing, and engineering thinks it means something else.